# How to return jsx based on which path the user is on

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

(Please note that I'm a complete beginner. Thank you for your patience.)
I have a navigation in my react app where I have 3 links, but once the user goes to another site, like for instance /about I would like the navigation bar to return a different link instead of a previous one, so instead of a chat icon going to /chat to the right of the navigation, it should change to an account icon that goes to /about).

I was thinking that I could do a if/else statement in the navigation component for each path.
I.e:
if (path == /about) {
return (
....
)
}

if (path == /home) {
return (
....
)
}

if (path == /checkout) {
return (
....
)
}

But I haven't managed to store which path the user is currently on.

I've tried to google and try different things out, but none unfortunately work for me.
Am I even thinking of the right solution to this feature?
If this is a matter of using hooks vs redux then I'd like to use hooks..

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you're using React Router, you can import `useLocation` from 'react-router-dom`:

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
```

The `useLocation` hook provides information about the current URL, including `pathname`, which is the variable you want to switch on:

```
// inside component:
const { pathname } = useLocation()

switch(pathname) {
  case '/checkout': {
    // return ...
  }
  case '/about': {
    // return ...
  }
  case '/home':
  default: {
    // return ...
  }
}
```